# Rails PostgreSQL non-case sensitive search with LIKE

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have this in my controller:

```
Konkurrencer.where("title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%").limit(4)
```

I think this query is case sensitive. It should not be case sensitive.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [`ILIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) in the where instead:

```
Konkurrencer.where("title ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%").limit(4)
```

From doc:

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match
>   case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the
>   SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

Answer (score 2):

For using case insensitive in search with PostgreSQL using LOWER...

Example:

```
def self.search(client, date_start, date_end)
       joins(:customer).where("LOWER(customers.name) LIKE ? AND date >= ? AND date <= ?", "%#{client}%", date_start, date_end)
end
```

Comment: Good solution, because works with PostgreSQL and Sqlite. I didn't test with MySQL. In my case I had to downcase the search term, for inst. "%#{client.downcase}%